# Nutch is not indexing content to solr but does not log any kind of error or waring

Tags: tomcat, logging, solr, nutch, solrj

I updated my nutch instance (on centos) from 1.4 to 1.8. For the frist 3-4 days it works just fine and was indexing anything to solr (3.5). But now nutch runs without any issue and also logs that the solr update is successful but there are no documents in the solr index.

Solr logs are also without any error or warning.

Does anyone has an idea what i'am missing? I'll tried allmost anything and searched hours for a solution.

regards

Answer (score 0):

I'll found the problem. There was a typo in the solrindex-mappings.xml. Eather Nutch nor Solr logged some kind of error even in debug mode, but after changing the solrindex-mappings everything worked just fine.